# IF Statement changing the format of an incorrect non numerical value in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

i have got this code:

```
 With .Cells(i, 6)
        If .NumberFormat <> "0.0%" Then
            .NumberFormat = "0.0%"
            If .Value2 <> vbNullString And IsNumeric(.Value2) Then .Value = .Value / 100
                If .Value2 = vbNullString Then
                    .Value = "---"
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
                End If
                    If .Value >= 0.9 Then
                        .Interior.Color = RGB(237, 67, 55)
                        .Font.Color = vbWhite
                    End If
        Else
            .Value = 0
        End If
    End With
```

what the code does is look for values in a column that are more than 90% and if so it formats the cell interior to red and the font to white. but i have got some cells on the same column that do not have any value and hence i wanted the cell to have this "---" in it to make it look tidy but when i run the code the cells with "---" in it get formated to red fill and white font as well.
what i want is for those cells to remain with their original formatting.

i have written this if statement but dont know what to write after the "THEN" part:

```
IF .Value = "---" Then
```

i am a rookie! thanks for your help!

Comment: Rather than writing code to do this, have a look at `Conditional Formatting' in Excel. Its built to do this kind of stuff

Comment: What is the original cell format before you change it to "0.0%"?

Comment: @Zac : you can set null values to "---", but setting "" to "---" does not seem possible to me

Comment: @Pierre, I don't think you can. I would use VBA to populate the cell values (where required) and let `Conditional Formatting` do the actual cell formatting ... a better approach in my view

Comment: @Zac You are right on this, indeed. Added to my answer to gain visibility ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

would this answer?

```
 With .Cells(i, 6)
        If .NumberFormat <> "0.0%" Then
            .NumberFormat = "0.0%"
            If .Value <> vbNullString And IsNumeric(.Value2) Then 
                .Value = .Value / 100
                if .Value >= 0.9 Then
                    .Interior.Color = RGB(237, 67, 55)
                    .Font.Color = vbWhite
                End If

            elseIf .Value = vbNullString Then
                    .Value = "---"
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
            Else
                stop 'I think you forgot this case
            end if
        Else
            .Value = 0
        End If
    End With
```

Edited: I add the suggestion of @Zac : use conditional formatting for the red color.

Answer (score 1):

Prioritize your tests, this should do the trick :

```
With .Cells(i, 6)
    If .NumberFormat <> "0.0%" Then
        .NumberFormat = "0.0%"
        If .Value2 <> vbNullString Then
            If IsNumeric(.Value2) Then .Value2 = .Value2 / 100
            If .Value2 >= 0.9 And .Value <> "---" Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(237, 67, 55)
                .Font.Color = vbWhite
            End If
        Else
            .Value = "---"
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        End If
    Else
        .Value = 0
    End If
End With
```